# Template of a DAO?

Tags: blockchain, alternatives, smartcontracts

Where can I find a simple smart contract template of a DAO? not The DAO, but a Decentralized Autonomous Organization, rules, codes, bylaws, responsibilities, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are are asking about Ethereum's popular DAO concept, the Ethereum Foundation website has a tutorial on creating a simple DAO application on https://www.ethereum.org/dao. Hope this helps!